# how to deal with backup & restore of private cloud environment?

Tags: backup, virtualization, vmware-esxi, xen, cloud

using Cloudstack OSS - with NFS as storage backend....

How to deal with VM image backup and restore? snapshot backup is preferred

softwares like PHD Virtual are built for specific Hypervisor: Citrix XenServer, VMware VSpehere.

AFAIK openstack offers API for storage backend not heard anything similar on cloudstack.

anyone has dealt with this before? thanks in advance